# Php Mysql SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE rowname = $variable

Tags: php, mysql

As usual thanks in advance. I've searched and searched for an answer to this but come up with a blank.

I know that the Variable `$userId` is fine as when echoing it spits out the number 8. However when trying to use it within my Mysql command the array just comes up with a blank.

I took that into account when searching for a NULL entry into the array with the `echo "Not";` but even that doesn't seem to echo out. Very strange. Is it simply that I need to change the way the `$userId` variable is put into the mysql statement?

```
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === "logged")
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
    $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
    echo 'The User ID = ' . $userId . '<br>';
    $musicidselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'") or die(mysql_error());

        while($data = mysql_fetch_array($musicidselect)){
            if($data){
                print_r($data);
            } else{
                echo "Not";
            }
        } 

    }
}
```

Am I having issues here simply because this file is loaded via jquery into another page?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
        $("#performsearch").click(function(){ 
             $("#displayresults").empty(); 
             $( "#displayresults" )
                  .html('<center><img src="http://www.#######.com/wp-content/themes/bigformat/images/ajax-loader.gif">‌​</center>')
                  .load( '/wp-content/themes/bigformat/template-home-search.php'); 
             return false; 
        }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  Is user_id an int or a string?  Do you get any errors, or just no rows returned?

Comment: Just to add further detail if I trim out the variable and simply enter the number 8 it works, thus why I'm almost 100% the entry of the variable is the problem.

Comment: Hi Barbara user_id is an int. No errors, just no rows returned. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $musicidselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = $userId") or die(mysql_error());
```

Since user_id is a number

FYI, variables with " "'s are evaluated, within ' ' are not.  See [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) for a nice description.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but still nothing echo's. very very strange!

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: It's generally a better idea to keep variables out of quotations and concat them with a dot.

Comment: @DanFromGermany - I disagree.  I think it makes much more readable code and the performance is similar.  Why do you prefer to concat?

Comment: @Barbara In the most common code style guides (PECL, Zend, ..), all suggest to concat or at least use `{$var}`. Putting variables in the quotes makes code less readable, IMO. Even the code highlighting on SO (see my answer below) shows this makes way more sense. Many newbies on SO start putting arrays and objects in quoted strings: `$test = "string $var['index'] string $object->object";` which actually throws errors / does not work. Sticking to the same rules in every case makes a way better code style.

Comment: Am I having issues here simply because this file is loaded via jquery into another page? `<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   $("#performsearch").click(function(){
  $("#displayresults").empty();
  $( "#displayresults" ).html('<center><img src="http://www.#######.com/wp-content/themes/bigformat/images/ajax-loader.gif"></center>').load( '/wp-content/themes/bigformat/template-home-search.php');
  return false;
 });
       
});
</script>`

Comment: @user3279268 - I don't think so, but have you tried going to the page directly?  What exactly does your sql statement that works look like?  And, what exactly does the variable $userId contain?

Comment: @DanFromGermany - lol I just saw answered a question where someone tried to use an array in "s.  I still disagree with using the lowest common denominator to determine best practices, but I see your point.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something really stupid here. It's getting late and my eyes are barely open. To clarify the session contains the id of '8' whilst the myMusic database DOES NOT it only has '34'. Therefore the page should echo I cant find the ID! BUT for some reason it always seems to echo from the if statement above saying 'Ive found the ID'????

Comment: `if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === "logged")
 { 
  if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
  {
  $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
  echo 'The User ID = ' . $userId . '<br>';
  $musicidselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id =" .$userId);
   if (!empty($musicidselect)) {
   //If ID value in table != Null then
   //$strSQL = "UPDATE users SET house=$houseaddition WHERE id='$userId'";
   echo 'Ive found the ID!';
   }
   else{
   echo 'Ive cant find the ID!';
   }
  
  
  }
 }`

Comment: I've finally solved it with the following!!! `// Is user logged in
 if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === "logged")
 { 
  if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
  {
  $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
  echo 'The User ID = ' . $userId . '<br>';
  $musicidselect = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id =" .$userId);
   if (empty($musicidselect)) {
   // This ID does not exist. Insert new Row into Table with ID.
   }
   else{
   // This ID exists. Make adjustments to current data
   }
  
  
  }
 }`

Answer (score 3):

This is not correct

```
"SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'"
```

should be as

```
"SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = '".$userId.'"
```

Comment: Both of you getting an upvote for the sake of one second

Comment: Hi thanks, but that did not work as it is actually a number stored as a variable!

Answer (score 3):

Wrong:

```
("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = '.$userId.'")
```

Correct:

```
("SELECT * FROM myMusic WHERE user_id = " . $userId)
```

Comment: Both of you getting an upvote for the sake of one second

Comment: @RobBaillie ofc, ID sounds like integer. Tho, this would not affect the result, quoting integers in MySQL is okay.

Comment: Hi thanks, but that did not work as it is actually a number stored as a variable!